Prove that Ito process is a submartingale
How to prove that the process $$X_t=X_0+\int_0^t h(s)ds+\int_0^t k(s)dw(s), h(s)\geq0$$ is a submartingale?

I am assuming $h,k$ are deterministic, so that
$$E[\int_0^t k(s)dw(s)|\mathcal{F}_{r}]=E[\int_{r}^{t}k(s)dw(s))|\mathcal{F}_{r}]+\int_0^{r}k(s)dw(s)=0+\int_0^{r}k(s)dw(s).$$
Therefore, using $h\geq 0$ we get:
$$E[X_{t}|\mathcal{F}_{r}]= X_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}h(s)ds+\int_0^{r}k(s)dw(s)\geq X_{r}.$$
